# going through old interview question in swift

Tags: swift

I have experience in android dev mostly. I am trying to expand into Swift and IOS. I think I understand why below would print out "B" but why would you ever use "let a: A = B()"? This just could be just simple screening question but I just couldn't come up with a reason to code this way. Help me out brothers!

```
class A{
    func printMsg(){
        print("A")
    }
}

class B: A{
    override func printMsg() {
        print("B")
    }
}

let a: A = B()
a.printMsg()
```

Comment: thats just simple polymorhpism

Comment: Is your question "why use `let a: A = B()` instead of `let a: B = B()`? If so, consider why you would ever say "I have a dog as a pet" instead of "I have a dog as a dog", or "What furniture do you have?" instead of the impossible-to-list "What tables and chairs and wardrobes and desks and chandeliers and.... do you have?". Sometimes you need to treat an object as a wider class than what it is.

Comment: Notably, there is nothing specific to Swift or iOS here - you would write exactly the same way (in a slightly different syntax) if you were to use Java.

Comment: @Amadan true. difference syntax usage was confusing me. esp why it wouldn't be "let a: A() = B()" instead of "let a: A = B()". I need to go back and read more of basics. thank you.

Comment: That would be like `A a = new B()` (correct Java) and `A() a = new B()` (incorrect Java).

Comment: wow... Thank you. for some reason this cleared my head.

Answer (score 1):

Here in `let a: A = B()`, constant property `a` is of type class A and we are assigning subclass B to it. We can only call overridden functions by this way, but if you add some other functions in subclass B, it wont be accessible. So this will call the overridden function and  print "B". If you do `let a: A = A()`, it will call the printMsg in class A and print "A". Also there is nothing wrong to write `let a: B = B()` and then print "B" like `a.printMsg()`. Both are the same.

Comment: will do in the future. currently i am getting the error saying, Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> but why would you ever use `let a: A = B()`?

In practice, you wouldn’t see that very often. They’re just testing your ability to understand the difference between the variable’s type, `A`, from the instance’s type, `B`. A far more common, practical, real-world example would be a function that takes an instance of `A` as a parameter:

```
func foo(a: A) { 
    a.printMsg()
}
```

So you have some function that will take any `A` type.

So, you could do things like:

```
let b = B()
foo(a: b)        // will print “B”
```

But, obviously, you could still do:

```
let a = A()
foo(a: a)        // will print “A”
```

The interview question of `let a: A = B()` is just a simplified rendition of the above. The fact that we’re using a `func` isn’t really relevant (though it’s the practical example). The interview question is focusing on the deeper question, namely your understanding of the distinction between the variable’s type and the instance’s type, specifically how it affects the determination as to which method implementation is called.

---

FWIW, the typical, advanced, follow-up to this particular interview question is often the protocol default implementation rendition, namely:

```
protocol C { }

extension C {
    func printMsg() {
        print("C")
    }
}

class D: C {
    func printMsg() {
        print("D")
    }
}

let c: C = D()
c.printMsg()      // will print “C”, not “D”!!!
```

As you’ll see, the behavior is different. If you want to get the same dynamic dispatch behavior with protocol types, the method in question has to be part of the protocol definition:

```
protocol C { 
    func printMsg()
}

// the rest is the same
```

Now, you’ll get “D”:

```
let c: C = D()
c.printMsg()      // will print “D”
```

Comment: amazing explanation. just blew my mind away. I really appreciate this.